# how to create movable nodes and edges in java swing GUI?

Tags: java, wpf, swing, user-interface, graph

In my java project, I need to create a GUI with swing where I will have a canvas like space. The user should be able to click and create nodes and then link nodes with edges (like you would create a UML diagram in MS Visio). The user should also be able to move the nodes along with edges. Then my application would save the network and run the selfish nodes algorithm and user should be able to see it live on GUI (creation and elimination of edges). I am not sure which swing tools I would need to use to accomplish this. (and can it be done in WPF, what tools I have to use for that)

Comment: Is this homework? What code have you got so far?

Comment: yes it's my school project, I haven't started any coding yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this one

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jgraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgraph</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

we really created very complex swing UI screen with a lot of graph oriented structures with this lib. take a look here http://www.jgraph.com or directly here http://www.jgraph.com/images/business-large.png Is this something you are looking for?

Comment: general question: can I build gui for my desktop java app using html5 and JS. If yes, what tools I need for that?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to "roll your own" solution, I have a few suggestions:

- Obviously you will need to use a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener which can be combined into a single entity by using a MouseAdapter.
- Your lines will likely be drawn in a JPanel's paintComponent method.
- Then your choices for nodes diverge. You can use components such as JLabels, each with a MouseAdapter attached (again as both a MouseListener and a MouseMotionListener)
- or you can use a single MouseAdapter added to a JPanel and render your nodes as rectangles again in the JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method.
- The data for the nodes and connections should be held separate from the GUI, perhaps in its own "model" class as part of an MVC (model-view-controller) application.
- The MouseAdapter would be part of the "control" of your MVC structure and would change the model.
- I prefer to be able to add listeners to my models, such as a PropertyChangeListener, and have the view, the Swing GUI, instigate a change of its display based on its listener being fired.

Since this is probably homework, I'll leave you to work out the details and code, but feel free to come back with your code if you get stuck at a specific step.

Comment: +1 for MVC. [`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) is an example that illustrates a few basic techniques.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to try out [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) library.
I've created an application with this library (instead of `JGraph`) because I thought that JUNG is easier to learn than `JGraph` for newbies (even if it provide less features). I needed only simple nodes and edges between them.

It look like this (probably this is more or less what you're trying to do):
[image: Application example]

Here is basic code snippet from core JUNG functionality:

```
public ArchitectureEditor(String title, MainWindow mainWindow, ArchObjContextConcern contextConcern) {
    super(title);
    setName(NAME);

    graph = new DirectedSparseGraph<ArchObject, EdgeKey>();

    layout = new StaticLayout<ArchObject, EdgeKey>(graph);
    vv = new AutoCropVisualizationViewer(layout); //extends VisualizationViewer<ArchObject, EdgeKey>
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(new EdgeShape.Line<ArchObject, EdgeKey>());

    VERTEX_ICON_TRANSFORMER = new ArchObjIconTransformer(vv);
    VERTEX_SHAPE_TRANSFORMER = new ArchObjShapeTransformer(vv);
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(VERTEX_SHAPE_TRANSFORMER);
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexIconTransformer(VERTEX_ICON_TRANSFORMER);

    graphMouse = new ArchGraphMouse(mainWindow, contextConcern);
    vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);
    vv.addKeyListener(new ArchGraphKeyboard(mainWindow, this));
    vv.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    ComponentUtils.setForcedSize(vv, 1, 1);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JScrollPane(vv));
}
```

And objects in graph are represented by:
[image: Class hierarchy]

Comment: Yes, I've considered using `JGraph` but JUNG at that moment seemed easier to learn.

Comment: Good point; I meant to endorse the value to the poster of learning/using a library in general, over the tedium of coding one by hand. +1 BTW.